# Can I embed a form response in the email that's written in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a script that sends an email of each response to a question on the form but I was wondering if I could somehow embed the form with responses in the email as like a PDF file or something. I'm not sure if it's even possible because I want it to send the form with the responses in it not just the blank form.

I want the email to look something like this:

Form has a new response. Here are all the answers.

(then we see the form with responses)

Comment: It's possible - what have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: As of now I have really just been looking for other examples to get an idea of where to start. I've sent emails of form responses in other scripts but that was different because I just retrieved them from the FormResponse class.

Comment: Break the task down into smaller elements. Create an "Installable" trigger using onFormSubmit(e)" - the code is triggered every time a new response is received; capture the form response details using the Event Objects. Create a PDF if you want (it's a royal pain but there are plenty of precedents) but also consider creating an html table of the response and inserting the table into your html email (again plenty of precedents). Taken as a whole this is complicated; taken as separate elements this is very doable  and there are many precedents on stackoverflow.